# Java слишком большие числа

Tags: java

Дали задание посчитать население с приростом в 4% каждый год,но есть проблема что 75 000 000 000 не вмещается в `int`/`double` и т.д как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 6):

Неправда, в double все должно помещаться, поскольку диапазон этого типа от 1.7е-308 до 1.7е+308 - более чем достаточно даже для всех атомов во вселенной.

Но вообще в этой задаче использование чисел с плавающей точкой особого смысла не имеет, поскольку речь идет о целочисленных величинах. Для представления чисел здесь должно хватить long, чей диапазон от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807

Comment: а они не теряют точности?

Comment: кто теряет в точности?

Comment: используй BigDecimal, точнее быть не может

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/201066/ вот хорошая статья про точность double, float

Comment: сталкивался с проблемами при больших вычислениях с double..

Comment: @МихаилКетов, это число сильно меньше 2^53.

Comment: @МихаилКетов при чем тут вообще double и его точность? В вопросе речь идет о населении, то есть о целочисленных величинах.  Вы же не предлагаете считать людей десятыми и сотыми долями человека? В этой задаче вообще не нужны типы с плавающей точкой, тут хватит обычного long, и ломать голову над точностью double здесь вовсе не имеет смысла.

Comment: Согласен.. Дабл оставим Декстеру.

Comment: @Александр нет,  BigDecimal здесь не нужен.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, согласен, хватит и long

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать `BigInteger`, если будете считать прирост на несколько тысячелетий)

Comment: Надеюсь, нас никогда не станет столько, чтобы понадобился `BigInteger` :)